# gradle dependency version conflict

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

I have the following dependency script:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'com.google.protobuf'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.3"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.asdf.asdf"
        minSdkVersion 10
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    buildTypes.each {
        it.buildConfigField 'String', 'YOUTUBE_API_KEY', YoutubeApiKey
    }
}

protobuf {
    protoc {
        artifact = 'com.google.protobuf:protoc:3.0.0-beta-2'
    }
    plugins {
        grpc {
            artifact = 'io.grpc:protoc-gen-grpc-java:0.13.2'
        }
    }
    generateProtoTasks {
        all().each { task ->
            task.builtins {
                javanano {
                    option 'ignore_services=true'
                }
            }

            task.plugins {
                grpc {
                    option 'nano=true'
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.2.1'
    compile 'com.mcxiaoke.volley:library:1.0.19'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.2.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.2.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:23.2.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-annotations:23.2.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:customtabs:23.2.1'
    compile 'com.google.apis:google-api-services-youtube:v3-rev164-1.21.0'
    compile 'javax.annotation:javax.annotation-api:1.2'
    compile 'io.grpc:grpc-protobuf-nano:0.13.2'
    compile 'io.grpc:grpc-okhttp:0.13.2'
    compile 'io.grpc:grpc-stub:0.13.2'
    compile 'com.google.guava:guava:18.0'
}
```

Though both the youtube library and the grpc library are dependent on the google guava library, they're reliant on different versions causing a conflict. Youtube is dependent on `com.google.guava:guava-jdk5:17.0` and grpc on `com.google.guava:guava:18.0`.(Notice the artifact difference, if that is possibly relevant) The problem is grpc ends up trying to locate a method defined in youtube's version of guava when it only exists in in its own version of the dependency. How do I resolve this?

**ERROR Message**

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: SyncAdapterThread-1
    Process: com.asdf.asdf, PID: 4025
             java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No static method directExecutor()Ljava/util/concurrent/Executor; in class Lcom/google/common/util/concurrent/MoreExecutors; or its super classes (declaration of 'com.google.common.util.concurrent.MoreExecutors' appears in /data/data/com.fentale.dalol/files/instant-run/dex/slice-guava-jdk5-17.0_a8ada10dcaf113cb6e3b4d3e5b46975833f8ae8f-classes.dex)
                at io.grpc.internal.ClientCallImpl.<init>(ClientCallImpl.java:100)
                at io.grpc.internal.ManagedChannelImpl$RealChannel.newCall(ManagedChannelImpl.java:320)
                at io.grpc.internal.ManagedChannelImpl.newCall(ManagedChannelImpl.java:299)
                at io.grpc.stub.ClientCalls.blockingUnaryCall(ClientCalls.java:130)
                at com.fentale.dalol.nano.DalolGrpc$DalolBlockingStub.topPosts(DalolGrpc.java:365)
```

The method "directExecutor" is defined in guava-v18, but grpc tries to access it from the `guava-jdk5`.

Comment: Please paste your error message.

Comment: Try removing the last line of your gradle

Comment: @barq I added the last line(guava dependency) according to your instructions. Doesn't work. Also tried forcing it in the project build, same result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would try to exclude guava-jdk5 by using

```
exclude module: 'guava-jdk5'
```

in your dependencies.

The problem is that version conflicts cannot be detected if the artifacts have different names (like here, guava and guava-jdk5). Then it can happen that the wrong classes are loaded because both jars are included.

Comment: Thanks. 
    compile ('com.google.apis:google-api-services-youtube:v3-rev164-1.21.0'){
            exclude module: 'guava-jdk5'
        }
That did it.

Comment: I attempted to use `exclude group: "com.google.guava", module: "guava-jdk5")}` for Firebase and YouTube, but I am seeing the same issue. This seems like it should of worked since the error is coming from Firebase: `at com.google.cloud.firestore.FirestoreImpl.streamRequest(FirestoreImpl.java:339)
 at com.google.cloud.firestore.Query.stream(Query.java:955)
 at com.google.cloud.firestore.Query.get(Query.java:995)
 at com.google.cloud.firestore.Query.get(Query.java:965)
 at content.Task.getQueryParams(ContentTasks.kt:69)
 at content.Task.run(ContentTasks.kt:54)`

Answer (score 1):

Specify the guava version manually

```
compile 'com.google.guava:guava:18.0.0'
```

So your dependencies will be the following

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.google.apis:google-api-services-youtube:v3-rev164-1.21.0'
    compile 'javax.annotation:javax.annotation-api:1.2'
    compile 'io.grpc:grpc-protobuf-nano:0.13.2'
    compile 'com.google.guava:guava:18.0.0' 
}
```

That way you will force guava v18 to be used.

Or in the top level gradle you can use

```
configurations.all {
    resolutionStrategy.force 'com.google.guava:guava:18.0.0'
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to edit project level **build.gradle** you have to

```
exclude module: 'guava-jdk5'
```

inside dependencies. Please check attached screenshot for more details[image]
If you are using firebase plugins add

```
classpath ('com.google.firebase:firebase-plugins:1.1.0') {
        exclude group: 'com.google.guava', module: 'guava-jdk5'
    }
```