# Kotlin Jar Error: Exception in thread "Timer-0" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError

Tags: java, intellij-idea, kotlin, jar, google-cloud-firestore

## Issue

The Kotlin app runs as expected from the **main** method in IntelliJ's IDE. However, after setting up the project on a new machine the compiled **Jar** throws the following exception which is related to a **Firestore** library:

**Error:** *Exception in thread "Timer-0" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.google.common.util.concurrent.MoreExecutors.directExecutor()Ljava/util/concurrent/Executor;*

**Full Error**

```
Exception in thread "Timer-0" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.google.common.util.concurrent.MoreExecutors.directExecutor()Ljava/util/concurrent/Executor;
at io.grpc.internal.ClientCallImpl.<init>(ClientCallImpl.java:96)
at io.grpc.internal.ManagedChannelImpl$RealChannel.newCall(ManagedChannelImpl.java:662)
at io.grpc.internal.CensusTracingModule$TracingClientInterceptor.interceptCall(CensusTracingModule.java:382)
at io.grpc.ClientInterceptors$InterceptorChannel.newCall(ClientInterceptors.java:104)
at io.grpc.internal.CensusStatsModule$StatsClientInterceptor.interceptCall(CensusStatsModule.java:675)
at io.grpc.ClientInterceptors$InterceptorChannel.newCall(ClientInterceptors.java:104)
at com.google.api.gax.grpc.GrpcHeaderInterceptor.interceptCall(GrpcHeaderInterceptor.java:81)
at io.grpc.ClientInterceptors$InterceptorChannel.newCall(ClientInterceptors.java:104)
at com.google.api.gax.grpc.GrpcMetadataHandlerInterceptor.interceptCall(GrpcMetadataHandlerInterceptor.java:55)
at io.grpc.ClientInterceptors$InterceptorChannel.newCall(ClientInterceptors.java:104)
at io.grpc.internal.ManagedChannelImpl.newCall(ManagedChannelImpl.java:636)
at com.google.api.gax.grpc.GrpcClientCalls.newCall(GrpcClientCalls.java:66)
at com.google.api.gax.grpc.GrpcDirectServerStreamingCallable.call(GrpcDirectServerStreamingCallable.java:65)
at com.google.api.gax.grpc.GrpcExceptionServerStreamingCallable.call(GrpcExceptionServerStreamingCallable.java:62)
at com.google.api.gax.rpc.WatchdogServerStreamingCallable.call(WatchdogServerStreamingCallable.java:69)
at com.google.api.gax.rpc.ServerStreamingCallable$1.call(ServerStreamingCallable.java:220)
at com.google.api.gax.rpc.ServerStreamingCallable$1.call(ServerStreamingCallable.java:220)
at com.google.api.gax.rpc.ServerStreamingCallable.serverStreamingCall(ServerStreamingCallable.java:166)
at com.google.api.gax.rpc.ServerStreamingCallable.serverStreamingCall(ServerStreamingCallable.java:178)
at com.google.cloud.firestore.FirestoreImpl.streamRequest(FirestoreImpl.java:339)
at com.google.cloud.firestore.Query.stream(Query.java:955)
at com.google.cloud.firestore.Query.get(Query.java:995)
at com.google.cloud.firestore.Query.get(Query.java:965)
at content.Task.getQueryParams(ContentTasks.kt:69)
at content.Task.run(ContentTasks.kt:54)
at java.base/java.util.TimerThread.mainLoop(Timer.java:556)
at java.base/java.util.TimerThread.run(Timer.java:506)
```

## Setup

*build.gradle* dependencies

```
compile "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8"
testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.12'
// JUnit Jupiter API and TestEngine implementation
testCompile("org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-api:${junitJupiterVersion}")
testRuntime("org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-engine:${junitJupiterVersion}")
testCompile("org.assertj:assertj-core:3.10.0")
// To avoid compiler warnings about @API annotations in JUnit code
testCompileOnly('org.apiguardian:apiguardian-api:1.0.0')
implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.3.0'
implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.3.0'
implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:adapter-rxjava:2.3.0'
implementation 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxjava:2.1.1'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-admin:6.3.0'
implementation 'com.google.apis:google-api-services-youtu be:v3-rev204-1.23.0'
```

*MANIFEST.MF*

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Main-Class: Initialization
```

## Attempted Solutions

1. Rebuilding Jar Artifact.
2. Rebuilding project.
3. Invalidating IntelliJ cache and restarting IDE.
4. Re-syncing Gradle file.
5. Restarting computer
6. Updated gradle libraries, excluded guava where older versions were used, and explicitly define **guava** and **com.google.api** libraries.

```js
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.3.10'
    ext.junitJupiterVersion  = '5.3.2'

    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
        classpath 'org.junit.platform:junit-platform-gradle-plugin:1.0.3'
    }
}

plugins {
    id 'java'
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.jvm' version '1.2.51'
}

version '1.0-SNAPSHOT'

sourceCompatibility = 1.8

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    implementation "com.google.guava:guava:27.0.1-jre"
    implementation ('com.google.api:gax:1.33.1') {
        exclude group: "com.google.guava", module: "guava"
    }
    implementation ('com.google.api:gax-grpc:1.33.1') {
        exclude group: "com.google.guava", module: "guava"
    }
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8"
    testImplementation group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '5.3.2'
    // JUnit Jupiter API and TestEngine implementation
    testImplementation("org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-api:${junitJupiterVersion}")
    testRuntime("org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-engine:${junitJupiterVersion}")
    testImplementation("org.assertj:assertj-core:3.11.1")
    // To avoid compiler warnings about @API annotations in JUnit code
    testCompileOnly('org.apiguardian:apiguardian-api:1.0.0')
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.5.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.5.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:adapter-rxjava:2.5.0'
    implementation 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxjava:2.2.4'
    implementation ('com.google.firebase:firebase-admin:6.6.0') {
        exclude group: "com.google.guava", module: "guava"
    }
    implementation ('com.google.apis:google-api-services-youtube:v3-rev206-1.25.0'){
        exclude group: "com.google.guava", module: "guava"
    }
}

compileKotlin {
    kotlinOptions.jvmTarget = "1.8"
}
compileTestKotlin {
    kotlinOptions.jvmTarget = "1.8"
}
```

**Guava dependencies with attempted solution #6:** `gradle dependencyInsight --dependency com.google.guava`

```
com.google.guava:failureaccess:1.0.1
    variant "runtime" [
      org.gradle.status                  = release (not requested)
  Requested attributes not found in the selected variant:
     org.gradle.usage                   = java-api
     org.jetbrains.kotlin.platform.type = jvm
   ]

com.google.guava:failureaccess:1.0.1
\--- com.google.guava:guava:27.0.1-jre
     \--- compileClasspath

com.google.guava:guava:27.0.1-jre
   variant "default" [
  org.gradle.status                  = release (not requested)
  Requested attributes not found in the selected variant:
     org.gradle.usage                   = java-api
     org.jetbrains.kotlin.platform.type = jvm
   ]

com.google.guava:guava:27.0.1-jre
\--- compileClasspath

com.google.guava:listenablefuture:9999.0-empty-to-avoid-conflict-with-guava
   variant "runtime" [
  org.gradle.status                  = release (not requested)
  Requested attributes not found in the selected variant:
     org.gradle.usage                   = java-api
     org.jetbrains.kotlin.platform.type = jvm
   ]

com.google.guava:listenablefuture:9999.0-empty-to-avoid-conflict-with-guava
\--- com.google.guava:guava:27.0.1-jre
     \--- compileClasspath
```

**Guava Versions Being Used**: `find ~/.gradle -name 'guava*.jar'`

```
Adams-MacBook-Pro:coinverse-media adamhurwitz$ find ~/.gradle -name 'guava*.jar'
/Users/adamhurwitz/.gradle/caches/jars-3/e78d086d43fe590d24040393ce6cb069/guava-21.0.jar
/Users/adamhurwitz/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/com.google.guava/guava/20.0/89507701249388e1ed5ddcf8c41f4ce1be7831ef/guava-20.0.jar
/Users/adamhurwitz/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/com.google.guava/guava/20.0/9c8493c7991464839b612d7547d6c263adf08f75/guava-20.0-sources.jar
/Users/adamhurwitz/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/com.google.guava/guava/23.0/c947004bb13d18182be60077ade044099e4f26f1/guava-23.0.jar
/Users/adamhurwitz/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/com.google.guava/guava/23.0/ed233607c5c11e1a13a3fd760033ed5d9fe525c2/guava-23.0-sources.jar
/Users/adamhurwitz/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/com.google.guava/guava/23.6-android/13f7bbf4f1b95dbec11df43200bfdb913ccd4072/guava-23.6-android.jar
/Users/adamhurwitz/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/com.google.guava/guava/23.6-android/92dee3d8391d9d45d8c6323bc350b606aac89a12/guava-23.6-android-sources.jar
/Users/adamhurwitz/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/com.google.guava/guava/27.0-jre/c6ad87d2575af8ac8ec38e28e75aefa882cc3a1f/guava-27.0-jre.jar
/Users/adamhurwitz/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/com.google.guava/guava/27.0-jre/d6484e2ee11ad928ccf61cf3e4ce9cedc2eead7e/guava-27.0-jre-sources.jar
/Users/adamhurwitz/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/com.google.guava/guava/27.0.1-jre/bd41a290787b5301e63929676d792c507bbc00ae/guava-27.0.1-jre.jar
/Users/adamhurwitz/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/com.google.guava/guava/27.0.1-jre/cb5c1119df8d41a428013289b193eba3ccaf5f60/guava-27.0.1-jre-sources.jar
/Users/adamhurwitz/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/com.google.guava/guava-jdk5/17.0/463f8378feba44df7ba7cd9272d01837dad62b36/guava-jdk5-17.0.jar
/Users/adamhurwitz/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/com.google.guava/guava-jdk5/17.0/cc6729ce0bc6cc29441cb3a04acad02aeeebb26e/guava-jdk5-17.0-sources.jar
/Users/adamhurwitz/.gradle/caches/transforms-1/files-1.1/guava-23.0.jar
/Users/adamhurwitz/.gradle/caches/transforms-1/files-1.1/guava-23.6-android.jar
/Users/adamhurwitz/.gradle/wrapper/dists/gradle-4.4-all/9br9xq1tocpiv8o6njlyu5op1/gradle-4.4/lib/guava-jdk5-17.0.jar
/Users/adamhurwitz/.gradle/wrapper/dists/gradle-4.6-all/bcst21l2brirad8k2ben1letg/gradle-4.6/lib/guava-jdk5-17.0.jar
```

Comment: Did you try to check if there are any dependency conflicts? https://stackoverflow.com/q/21311727/1654233 can perhaps help.

Comment: Thanks @yegodm! I created a dependency report: [scans.gradle.com/s/qmwmf3z55zdq6](https://scans.gradle.com/s/qmwmf3z55zdq6/). What strategy would you recommend for identifying which conflict(s) are causing the issue?

Comment: The strategy is always the same - identify the library which causing the problem ( I guess it is Google guava), and figure out which version (19.0 vs 20.0) does not have the method reported by the exception. Then you'll have to find the way how to enforce the proper version in Gradle.

Comment: I attempted to exclude **guava** from both the Firebase and YouTube libraries without success.  `implementation ('com.google.firebase:firebase-admin:6.6.0') {
        exclude group: "com.google.guava", module: "guava"
    }
    implementation ('com.google.apis:google-api-services-youtube:v3-rev206-1.25.0'){
        exclude group: "com.google.guava", module: "guava"
    }` while implementing the latest **guava** version: `api "com.google.guava:guava:27.0.1-jre"`

Comment: In the link in your previous question, there's ``guava:27.0-android`. You can't use `-android` and `-jre` at the same time.  `+++` A different approach: Remove your `~/.gradle` directory and let gradle compile your project. With `find ~/.gradle -name 'guava*.jar'`, you'll see what Guava versions get used.

Comment: Looks like runtime classpath is very different. The method has been since 18.0, and you somehow endup with earlier version.

Comment: @maaartinus, good call. I've adjusted to use `api "com.google.guava:guava:27.0.1-jre"`.

Comment: @yegodm, May you please elaborate on the **classpath**? Which classpath is different from what?

Comment: I'm not an Android expert, but I'd try something like this https://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-print-out-the-current-project-classpath/ to dump actual runtime classpath to a log/console.

Comment: @maaartinus - I've done as recommended removing the `gradle` dir and letting it re-compile. I've posted the results of the command `find ~/.gradle -name 'guava*.jar'` above under the attempted solutions section. It looks like some Android dependencies are being called which could be potentially an issue since this is purely a AppEngine Kotlin/Java Jar project.

Comment: @yegodm, I believe @maaartinus' method of `find ~/.gradle -name 'guava*.jar'` produced the same result. I've posted the results under the *Attempted Solutions* section in my post above. It appears both Android and older versions of Guava are showing. Could that be the root of the issue?

Comment: I was talking about actual classpath of running application. Anyway I'd suspect guava-jdk5-17.0.jar is the culprit.

Comment: How can I resolve this @yegodm? When I do  `gradle dependencies --scan` and search for `guava-jdk5-17.0.jar` in the output log it does not show under any of the libraries... Output log: [scans.gradle.com/s/fyqwsge3gvja2/console-log](https://scans.gradle.com/s/fyqwsge3gvja2/console-log)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/36403041/1654233 ?

Comment: I attempted to use `exclude group: "com.google.guava", module: "guava-jdk5")}` for Firebase and YouTube, but I am seeing the same issue. This seems like it should of worked since the error is coming from Firebase: `at com.google.cloud.firestore.FirestoreImpl.streamRequest(FirestoreImpl.java:339)
 at com.google.cloud.firestore.Query.stream(Query.java:955)
 at com.google.cloud.firestore.Query.get(Query.java:995)
 at com.google.cloud.firestore.Query.get(Query.java:965)
 at content.Task.getQueryParams(ContentTasks.kt:69)
 at content.Task.run(ContentTasks.kt:54)`

Comment: What `module: "guava-jdk5"`?  I don't know the exact syntax, but shouldn't it be `name` (just like in `compile`)? `+++` Does deleting the old dependency from `~/.gradle` help? `+++` It doesn't matter where the exception comes from, as the culprit is the part using the old version (assuming you prefer the new one).

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried updating your GAX-Java dependency past version 1.33.1? It looks like version 1.35.0 uses Guava 26.0.

Comment: Thanks @netdpb. Fortunately, I was able to remove the explicit `GAX-Java` dependency.